How should I use soft and forced rollouts in DDI API?
I created two rollouts, one with type soft and the other one with type forced. When using DDI API fetching a controller in the different rollouts the have the same attributes. I expected some information for a controller in the soft rollout that it needed confirmation, but for both the response using /controller/v1/[myControllerId] I get this response:
{
    "config": {
        "polling": {
            "sleep": "00:05:00"
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "deploymentBase": {
            "href": "http://eslm-hawkbit.dev-eslm.dss.husqvarnagroup.net/DEFAULT/controller/v1/[myControllerId]/deploymentBase/681579?c=-1496966704"
        },
        "configData": {
            "href": "http://eslm-hawkbit.dev-eslm.dss.husqvarnagroup.net/DEFAULT/controller/v1/[myControllerId]/configData"
        }
    }
}

How do we know if it is ok to start download or if we should wait for confirmation?
